# Newsstand App Library backgorund

Tags: ios5, newsstand-kit

I want to implement a Newsstand App and I have seen that almost Newsstand App have the same background for the Library, the first screen of the app, same xib, but with their own covers for their magazine. It this xib available somewhere so that I could also use it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to implement your own view controller.